# Popup model view show black screen in rotated parent viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a ViewController, which contains a button. In start-up, I rotate the window by PI radius. In appplication:didFinishLanchingWithOptions function add follow codes:

```
[application setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown];
self.window.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
```

I hope click the button to popup a model view (by presentViewController function), but  I only see a black screen. The button click event:

```
- (void)btnAction:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiate...WithIdentifier:@"modal";
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completation:nil]; // unexpected behavior
    // [self.navigattionController pushViewController:vc]; // expected behavior
}
```

By debug I know the modal view's center has some offset but I can not correct it.  When I use push segue to replace it, it has right behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your application you see black screen or after clicking button to show your modal view.
that is called black popup screen.